# Handle old PHP script path in new Yii2 app

Tags: php, nginx, routes, yii2

I have an URL on my old site to some WebAPI interface, script is located at:

`http://www.example.com/interface/api.php`

I'm migrating everything to Yii2 and I can't find out how to handle this redirection route in Yii2, so I can handle it directly in my Yii2's controllers.

I've tried in my urlManager settings this

`[ 'pattern' => 'interface/api', 'route' => 'site/interface-api', 'suffix' => '.php' ],`

but nginx comes into play with its own error message. It seems like the ".php" extension here is the problem and nginx takes control first before the Yii2.

Is there any way to handle it in Yii2 or do I have to play with nginx settings?

Answer (score -1):

Add an `.htaccess` file on `web` folder, with the redirection to `index.php`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

In configs try this:

```
'components' => [
  'urlManager' => [
    'suffix' => '.php',
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        'interface/api' => 'site/interface-api'
    ]
  ],
],
```

**update for nginx:**

```
location / {
        index  index.html $yii_bootstrap;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$yii_bootstrap?$args;
    }
```

Add this configuration to your nginx config. Full guide [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.apache-nginx-config)

Comment: It's not Apache - it's nginx and it doesn't work with .php suffix and nginx default settings.

Comment: Updated my answer, added a link to guide